# Mongo Atlas combine $search with match

Tags: mongodb, match, atlas, text-search

I'm searching through a collection either by *hard* data (numbers, other values) with $match and operaters like $regex, $in, $eq, $size, $gte, etc.

```
{'$match': {'$and': [{'isbn': {'$exists': 1}}, {'form': {'$in': ['BC']}}]}}
```

With $facet I can **count** the found matches.

For other purposes I use a $search index for nifty text search. I get scores and highlight and the lots, and again (but not with $facet) the **count** of found matches.

```
$search': {
    'index': 'default',
    'compound': {
        'must': [
            how...
        ],
    },
    'count': {'type': 'total'},
}
```

I can combine $match and $search, but cannot get a proper count. $search is not combinable with $facet, and without the $facet the text search always counts what the text search finds, not taking into account the unmatched documents.

How can I combina the both? Adding compound filters or using the limitied amount of operators within Atlas's text search are not sufficient.

Bottom line, this is all about proper **counting of results**.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you attach sample json documents and expected output? Currently it is unclear what count should be expected and why do you think it is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't.

The `$search` stage uses a completely different index and methodology to "match" documents, therefor there are the limitations that it has to be the first step in a pipeline and can't be nested in a `$facet`.

Removing these limitations will essentially just run 2 queries, which is what you must do.

```
const count = await collection.aggregate([...matchStage, ...countStage])
const highlights = await collection.aggregate([...searchStage, ...matchStage])
```

An approach that is possible in ElasticSearch is to use the [children](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-children-aggregation.html)  pipeline, but as far as i'm aware this is not a feature available on atlas search yet.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. I was afraid that would be the answer. So, first match on hard criteria and project only the _id's. Then do the textsearch, with the set of _id's as filter. That is two queries, but it will give the requered results.

Can Atlas TextSearch be combined with a subset from a $lookup with $documents stage?

Comment: Yes, for MongoDB v6.0+ https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/atlas-search/tutorial/lookup-with-search/#:~:text=Starting%20in%20v6.,further%20narrow%20down%20your%20search.

but mind you from compute perspective it's equivalent to two separate queries, so if the first one just needs to count and there's no pipeline continuation then there's no big benefit in joining them.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution!**

What is not menioned in the documentation (at least not findable), is the possibility to use regex in a filter.

This way i can replace the whole match part.

```
'$search': {
      'index': "default",
      'compound':{
        'filter': [
            {
                'regex': { # to find specific years in dates
                    'query': '(2019|2020|2021|2022)',
                    'path': ['pubdate'],
                    'allowAnalyzedField': True,
                }
            },
            {
                'regex': {
                    'query': '(00|02|04)',
                    'path': ['pubstatus'],
                    'allowAnalyzedField': True,
                }
            },
            {
                'regex': { # look for BB or BC
                    'query': '(B.)',
                    'path': ['form'],
                    'allowAnalyzedField': True,
                }
            },
            {
                'regex': {
                    'query': '.*', # not empty
                    'path': ['cover'],
                    'allowAnalyzedField': True,
                }
            },
            {
                'regex': {
                    'query': '.*', # also to check if any items in the array
                    'path': ['index_recipes.recipe'],
                    'allowAnalyzedField': True,
                }
            }
        ],
        'must': [{ # the actual text search
          'text': {
            'query': "pizza pasta",
            'path': ['title', 'flaptext']
          }
        }]
      }
    }
  }
```

And it works fast and perfect.

Thanks for the help.